# Z-Index with different parents

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm having some trouble with the z-index.
This is my simplified layout:

```
<div id="overlapper"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

I need `overlapper` to appear in front of `child1` but behind `child2`.
I tried messing around with z index but it didn't work,  I think because of the stacking context.

Any help please?
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, make sure that `overlapper`, `child1` and `child2` belong to the same stacking context.

That is, make sure `container` doesn't create a stacking context:

- `container` must not be the root element.
- `container` must have the default value for [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) and [`isolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation) properties:

  - `position: static` or `z-index: auto`
  - `opacity: 1`
  - `isolation: auto`

Now, make `overlapper`, `child1` and `child2` positioned elements, and add `z-index` as you want.

```css
#overlapper, #child1, #child2 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}
#overlapper {
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
  top: 60px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#container {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
#child1 {
  z-index: 2;
  background: green;
  top: -40px;
}
#child2 {
  z-index: 4;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlapper">Overlapper</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1">Child 1</div>
    <div id="child2">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="overlapper"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlapper, #child1, #child2
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
#overlapper
{
    background: red;
    top : 40px;
    left : 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#child1
{
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 0;
}
#child2
{
    top: 60px;
    left : 60px;
    background: black; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[**Fidle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/u1d5jry1/3/)