# Z indexing across different parents in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I am starting out in React Native after coming from web and am confused as why the following is not rendering as expected.

```
<View style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <View>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              position: "absolute",
              zIndex: 3,
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              position: "absolute",
              left: 50,
              zIndex: 1,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            backgroundColor: "green",
            position: "absolute",
            top: 20,
            left: 50,
            zIndex: 2,
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

I am testing out z indexing and am trying to have an example where red is ontop of blue and green, while green is ontop of blue even though green is not a direct sibling of red and blue.

However, this is not the result I am getting. Instead I am getting green on top even though it has a lesser z index than red.

[image]

Anyone have suggestions here? Tried following the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329962/z-index-with-different-parents) but got the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child

Answer (score 0):

"green" zIndex will be compared to "red" and "blue" parent View, as it is in the same level with their parent.

Below works. "green" is

> position: "absolute"

and it will generate the same results as your example but reflects zIndex orders.

```
<View style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: 3,
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          position: "absolute",
          left: 50,
          zIndex: 1,
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          backgroundColor: "green",
          position: "absolute",
          top: 20,
          left: 50,
          zIndex: 2,
        }}
      />
</View>
```